# Border control for rounded image doesn't work on iOS [.net maui]

Tags: ios, xaml

I am using .net maui. Now, I make a rounded image with border control. It can works on Android  emulator but it doesn't work on iOS emulator. I have tried a lot of code online but both of them didn't work. Does anyone know how to solve it? Sorry for the blurry image. Hope you can see the differences.

Here is my code:

```
 <Border
    HeightRequest="50"
    WidthRequest="50">
    <Border.StrokeShape>
       <Ellipse/>
    </Border.StrokeShape>
                                    
    <Image
       Source="video_img_1.jpg"
       Aspect="AspectFill">
    </Image>
</Border>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUmDc.png)

I hope someone can share your solution with me. Thanks!